# Excel: How to search if spreadsheet1 value(s) exist in spreadsheet2 through VBA

Tags: excel, vba

In spreadsheet1, column B contains values (i.e. V-9999). I'm trying to see if those values exist in spreadsheet2 column B. The issue I'm running into is that the data changes each time I update the spreadsheet and it's not always a 1:1 match between each row in column B.

For example, V-9999 may exist in cell B7 in spreadsheet1 but in spreadsheet2 V-9999 resides in cell B13. I've tried this, but I think the issue is it's trying to compare the cells for a 1:1 match, and not the actual cell value V-9999.

I'm using V-9999 as an example, but the value will change every week and can be any number between 1-100,000 pretty much, so doing a check for that whole range since inefficient instead of just checking the explicit values in spreadsheet1 and comparing to spreadsheet2.

- spreadsheet1 = Current
- spreadsheet2 = Previous
- both spreadsheets are in the same workbook
- I'm also trying to highlight the differences (spreadsheet1 will be highlighted in red for values that aren't in spreadsheet2, spreadsheet2 will be highlighted in green for values that aren't in spreadsheet1)

```
Sub CompareSheets()
    Dim rngCell As Range

    For Each rngCell In Worksheets("Current").Range("B2:B9999")
        If Not rngCell = Worksheets("Previous").Cells(rngCell.Column) Then _
            rngCell.Interior.Color = vbRed
        Next
        
        For Each rngCell In Worksheets("Previous").Range("B2:B9999")
            If Not rngCell = Worksheets("Current").Cells(rngCell.Column) Then _
                rngCell.Interior.Color = vbGreen
        Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Dictionary object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dictionary-object) for this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CompareSheets()
    Const RNG_ADDRESS = "B2:B9999"
    ' set a reference to 'Microsoft Scripting Runtime' in Tools->References VBE menu
    Dim dict1 As New Dictionary, dict2 As New Dictionary
    Dim rngCell As Range
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ' make the first dictionary
    For Each rngCell In Worksheets("Current").Range(RNG_ADDRESS)
        If Not dict1.Exists(rngCell.Text) Then dict1.Add rngCell.Text, vbNullString
    Next
    
    ' make the second dictionary
    For Each rngCell In Worksheets("Previous").Range(RNG_ADDRESS)
        If Not dict2.Exists(rngCell.Text) Then dict2.Add rngCell.Text, vbNullString
    Next
        
    ' paint cells in the Worksheets("Current") in red
    For Each rngCell In Worksheets("Current").Range(RNG_ADDRESS)
        If Not dict2.Exists(rngCell.Text) Then
            rngCell.Interior.Color = vbRed
        Else
            rngCell.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
        End If
    Next
    
    ' paint cells in the Worksheets("Previous") in green
    For Each rngCell In Worksheets("Previous").Range(RNG_ADDRESS)
        If Not dict1.Exists(rngCell.Text) Then
            rngCell.Interior.Color = vbGreen
        Else
            rngCell.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
        End If
    Next
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```